# DNS client source interface in linux

Tags: linux-networking

I want to configure which ifIndex to use as the source interface to send DNS packets out on.

How I can do it in a DNS client in Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source interface and source address are determined by the normal routing tables. If you don't like the source address, you can add iptables SNAT rules to change the source address.

Comment: Thanks using iptables or ip-rule?

Comment: iptables to change the source address. Could you explain why you want to do that?

Comment: I want to support ability to configure a "source intf" in my app for the dns client, more on lines of https://www.cisco.com/c/m/en_us/techdoc/dc/reference/cli/nxos/commands/sm/ip-dns-source-interface.html